# C++ to C# conversion failed because of returning a structure pointer (AmiBroker)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I am working on Amibroker C# plugin project. Amibroker SDK is written in C++ but, I am using a C# plugin which does exactly what Amibroker C++ does [C# plugin link](http://amibroker.codeplex.com/)
Everything in C# plugin works just fine except one function which is written in c++ this way:

```
PLUGINAPI struct RecentInfo* GetRecentInfo(LPCTSTR ticker)
{
   //Process & return RecentInfo* (RecentInfo is a structure)
}
```

In C# standard plugin it has been converted this way

```
public RecentInfo GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return RecentInfo
}
```

Unfortunately, Amibroker application crashes with this wrong conversion. So I did try to convert it my way to get Amibroker App working, but failed multiple times This is what i have tried so far:

Attemp 1:

```
unsafe public RecentInfo* GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return RecentInfo* (RecentInfo structure is declared as unsafe)
}
```

Impact:

Amibroker app does not load

Attemp 2:

```
public IntPtr GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return Pointer using Marshal.StructureToPtr
}
```

Impact:

Amibroker app does not load

Attemp 3:

```
public void GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Useless becoz no return type
}
```

Impact:

Amibroker loads & does call function correctly but how do return a structure pointer

So, I am scratching my head to find out the exact conversion of C++ function in C#